# Firebase delete query in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have list of comments in post.

On adding comments to post node , I have used `childbyautoid()`.
and I have set `commenttext`, `timestamp` and `userid` as values for comment.

CASE:
I want to delete my comment in the post.

Problem: 
How can I delete the comment according to `userid = myuserid`?

Went through many examples but couldn't found any?

Answer (score 1):

- You have to query all the node in comments. After querying all the autoId's in the node, you have to check for user id in each snapshot.
- In that snapshot, you have to compare your user id and if it matches, you have take the autoId of that snapshot and delete it.